# How to provide a default value for binding in a function argument?

Tags: rust

How can I provide a default literal value for a binding in a case which contains no fields to bind?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Descriptor {
    name: String,
    note: Option<String>,
}

fn func2(
    (d @ Descriptor {
        note: (Some(note_content) | None),
        ..
    }): &Descriptor,
) {
}
```

This will not compile since there is no binding for `note_content` in the `None` case. I would like to specify one, but I don't know the proper syntax.

This does not do the trick:

```
Some(note_content) | None, note_content @ "default literal".to_string()
```

What should be written there?

Comment: Do you really want a 1-tuple of `Descriptor` ?

Answer (score 6):

Patterns in functions need to be irrefutable. There is no way to do pattern matching in the parameter of a function — it doesn't make sense.

People use this feature to deconstruct irrefutable patterns like tuples. For example: `fn foo((a, b): (&Descriptor, &Descriptor))`, there are other use cases, but they're limited.

You could also do something like this, removing one layer of naming:

```rust
fn func2(Descriptor { name, note }: &Descriptor) {
    let note = note.as_deref().unwrap_or("default literal");
    println!("{}, {}", name, note);
}
```

You can't match refutable patterns like `Option` and there is no way to give a default value like you ask.

Comment: Well, I got it. I hoped it is possible to specify this right in the argument list.